# PHP Drop down List . Saving data to post on other pages in form

Tags: php, list, drop-down-menu

I have been searching for an answer to this for the last two days. 
I am trying to add a list of manufacturers to an existing form in php. 
This worked out ok and I got it to work somewhat.

Here is the problem when the user makes the selection and submits the form
it takes them to another page that shows them a preview of their post.
In this preview it show them the manufacturer they selected. But when they finalize the the 
post it doesn't show using the same code.

I know that their must be a simple way of doing this. I am not great with php but I have put forth a valiant effort to get this done. I am stumped please help.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<select action="select.php" name="manufacturer">
    <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
    <option value="Example">Example</option>
    </select>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['manufactuer']))
echo "Manufacturer: ".$_POST['manufacturer'];
  else {?>
```

I call to the selection with this.

```
<?php echo "Manufacturer: ".$_POST['manufacturer']; ?>
```

How do I show this when the user posts and if the same user posts again or a different user posts to show their selections for those specific posts.
posts

Comment: The action component shouldn't be in your <select> but in your <form>

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your variable on from your "review" page to your next page with a hidden field.

```
<form><input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST['manufacturer']; ?>' name='manufacturer' /></form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not sure if I worded my question right. I need to some how store the selection made and then display that selection in the users final post. Do you know how I can do this in php?

Comment: It seems like when I use this method then it only displays it for the current session. When someone else looks at the users post they don't see it at all.

Comment: Yep, snicksie's comment covers that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `selected="selected"` option in the selected select with php. That makes:

```
<option value="Lincoln" selected="selected">Lincoln</option>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not sure if I worded my question right. I need to some how store the selection made and then display that selection in the users final post. Do you know how I can do this in php?

Comment: another option is saving it in the session. If you do not save the selection the user selected, you cannot get it back. It means you need resend it (using the option Scott Rowley or I mentioned) or you need to save it in the session, that will save it too.

Comment: Thank you for your help and being patient with me.

Comment: This is basically what i need. I need users to select a manufacturer to post on a classified ad. When the users make the selection I need that information processed and sent to the page I point it to permanently for other users to see. The same for any user that makes a post.